# How to set up full text search for deeply nested JSON documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, full-text-search, algolia

Taking into account this example JSON document in database:

```
{
  text: 'grandparent',
  children: [
    {
      text: 'parent',
      children: [
        {
          text: 'child'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a possibility to setup full text search for nested JSON documents? What I'm looking for exactly is a possibility to search in deeply nested dynamic documents and receiving direct reference to found object (`search('child') => { text: 'child' }`) or some kind of path of properties (in this case like `/children/0/children/0`).

Answer (score 0):

What you have is `nested` in elastic search. [Refer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested)

You can query as `children.text : child`

```
{
 "query": {
  "bool": {
   "must": 
     { "match": { "children.texr": "child" }}
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it. Seems it's not working properly for nested objects. Works only on the top level (meaning "grandparent").

Comment: @Moddest can you add a document which you are expecting to match and the response you are getting